# Install devDependencies and dependencies together with yarn

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Is it possible to install `devDependencies` and `dependencies` together with yarn?

For example, if I want to install `react` and `webpack`. React is a dependency and webpack is a dev dependency. To install both, I need to run these two commands

```
yarn add react
yarn add webpack -D
```

Is is possible to combine them into one command or is there any alternative? Like installing both devDependencies and dependencies at the same time without running multiple commands.

Answer (score 61):

I don't think it is possible. [Documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add) does not specify such option, and if you provide at least one flag modifying type of dependencies - all dependencies specified in a command will become this type. If you really want to be one command to paste into command line you could do this:

```
yarn add react && yarn add webpack -D
```

Answer (score 29):

I think `yarn add --dev @packageName` should work

Answer (score 21):

`yarn install --production=false` should be helpful here I suppose. It should install both `devDependencies` and `dependencies`. Here is a link to the reference. https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/